# UITableView can be dragged up and down, not allowing Swipe Gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am a beginner in Swift, and am trying to add a swipe gesture recognizer to my UIView. I have inserted a gradient CALayer to index 0 to have a gradient background.

My problem is:

Swipe gestures for right and left work fine, but for Down it doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the delegate of swipe gestures that you are adding to the view.

```
let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipe:"))
swipeGesture.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
self.mySwipeGesture = swipeGesture
```

GestureRecognizerDelegate asks if two gesture recognizers should be allowed to recognize gestures simultaneously. Return `true` to allow both *gestureRecognizer* and *otherGestureRecognizer* to recognize their gestures simultaneously. The default implementation returns `false`—no two gestures can be recognized simultaneously. Implement the following delegate to achieve this.

```
extension ViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    //Identify gesture recognizer and return true else false.
    return gestureRecognizer.isEqual(self.mySwipeGesture) ? true : false
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain where and what to put in this? Sorry, but bear with me I am a beginner here :)

Answer (score 0):

Swiping Up & Down are the default property of table view. I would suggest you to disable the scrolling of the table view whenever you want to do something on the overlay.

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

If you are performing dragging of a particular cell then long press on it and then start dragging.

This is how you can achieve this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this, its just that I need the ability to scroll in the app I am making, thanks for your time :)

Comment: It is a todo list application